# Why We Couldn't Use Two Different enum Interchangeable?, e.g. As Function Parameter?

Tags: c++, c, enums

With this code:

```cpp
enum A { _1 };
enum B { _2 };

void f(A) {}

int main()
{
        f(_2);
}
```

A C++ compiler complains that couldn't convert `B` to `A` <sub>([try it on Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ojl8u3p1hoUPwOA2))</sub>, But with a C compiler we just get a warning <sub>(I know C++ is not C)</sub>:

```sh
main.c: In function ‘f’:
main.c:11:6: warning: type of ‘A’ defaults to ‘int’ [-Wimplicit-int]
   11 | void f(A)
      |      ^
main.c:11:6: warning: unused parameter ‘A’ [-Wunused-parameter]
```

Which it's make sense (for me) because as far as I know: An `enum` is just an `int` (whatever `short int`, `int`, ... depending on the value of the enumerations). So:

1. Why the C++ compiler doesn't let me use `B` as `A`?
2. And it's fine to use `f(static_cast<A>(_2));`?

---

My environment:

- Compiler: `GCC 11.1.0`
- Compiler Flags: `-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic`
- OS: `ArchLinux 5.13.13-arch1-1`

Comment: they are two different types, and inhibiting implicit conversions is a good thing

Comment: The warning is because this isn't conformant C either IIRC.

Comment: The whole point of enums is to keep `_1` separate from `_2`, even if they have the same value in binary code.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number, I thought what you say is just true for `enum class`es.

Comment: only `enum class` inhibits implicit conversion to the underlying type. The enum is not "just an `int`". That is a false premise. (and consider that implicit conversions consider only 1 step of user defined conversion)

Comment: C++ is somewhat more strict than C (thus some people use C++ as a better C). `enum class` is essentially what `enum` should have been from the beginning (without breaking backward compatibility).

Comment: Because if you wanted just an int, you would have written just an int. Presumably, since you wrote an enum, you would like the computer to tell you that you accidentally used the wrong enum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++, the function

```
void f(A) {}
```

is interpreted to mean “a function named f that takes an argument of type A, and its parameter has no name.” However, the C language requires that all function parameters have names (this is different than C++), so C interprets this as “a function f that takes a parameter named A, and since A has no associated type the compiler thinks it’s looking at older C code in which parameters with no names have type int, so that’s a function named f taking an int named A.” The warning you get from gcc is trying to tell you that, but it’s hard to know what it means without that backstory. (The use of function parameters without types as implicitly being integers is something that hasn’t been legal C for decades, but for backwards compatibility some C compilers accept it anyway.)

Independently - enumerated types have integral values but are not themselves integers. In both C and C++ you can implicitly convert an integer to an enumerated type. However, in C++ (and I believe C as well, but I’m not sure) enumerated values aren’t integers and can’t be treated as enumerated values of another type without a cast. So yes, you could call the function by explicitly casting one enumerated type to another, but you can’t call the function by passing an enumerated constant of the wrong type.

Comment: The main issue is that C does not make the bare tag an alias for the type -- you need to add `typedef enum A A;` to make `A` a type in C.

Comment: @ChrisDodd Correct me if I’m wrong, but wouldn’t that still lead to the problem of the function needing both a type and name for its argument? (It’s been a while since I did straight C programming, so let me know if this has changed.)

Comment: I think this varies by version (or extension) -- but the warning in the OPs code comes from the fact that `A` is not a type in C.